# AWS Application Load Balancer Redirect Path

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to configure a rule on my ALB's HTPP Port 80 listener.

The aim is to redirect to a different path "/fixtures.html" but keep it at HTTP

However when i deploy this i get loop errors in chrome,

Am I don't something wrong? Can you not redirect HTTP to HTTP?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you include the details of the redirect rule, and any other redirect rules you have configured for the load balancer? There should be no issue redirecting HTTP to HTTP, so to help you further we need more details about what you are doing.

Comment: Sure:
This is the only rule attached to the load balancer (except the default one).
IF -
Source IP is x.x.x.x/x
THEN - 
Redirect to HTTP - 80
Host - #{host} - Default
Path - /fixtures.html - the page i'm trying to redirect to
Query - #{query}
301 - Permanently Moved

Comment: @beth as Mark mentioned, please include the detail configuration and rules of ALB in the Question itself. I also recommend to include version and system info that you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

That rule will redirect the user to that path, and cause the user's browser to send a new request for that `/fixtures.html` file. On that second request, the user's IP still matches the IP in the redirect rule, so it will issue another redirect. Thus the redirect loop you are running into.

Since you can't currently negate conditions in ALB rules, you can't add a condition for "path is not /fixtures.html", so this is going to be a bit difficult to do correctly through ALB listener rules. You may be better off adding this redirect condition inside your web server's configuration where you instead of in the load balancer's configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your help Mark. Is there any other way of implementing this redirection without changing any web server configuration?
What about if the IF Statement didn't need to be from a source IP Address?